# Forward error correction

Tags: coding-theory

I have a data stream with following properties:

- Binary
- Dynamic length
- Comes in blocks of 20 bits
- Any random bits may flip creating an error (there isn't more probability that adjacent bits to flip together)
- I would like to use around 16 bits as data and 4 for redundancy per block, but I am open to change that number
- The probability that a bit is correct is around 97%
- Ideally, the code would be able to correct 2 bits per block
- The amount of blocks will be rather small, usually 1-6.

What would be a good code to use in this scenario? I thought of Reed-Solomon, but according to [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/305641094_Error_Detection_and_Correction_Using_Reed_Solomon_Codes) it would be a poor choice:

```
if a data stream is not characterized by error bursts or drop-outs but by random single bit errors, 
a Reed-Solomon code is usually a poor choice. More effective codes are available for this case.
```

I've also looked into `Bossen's b-adjacent algorithm`, but it seems to be designed taking into account that adjacent bit-flips have higher probability of happening.

Comment: I think you are being too optimist. With $n=20$ and $t=2$ (two errors correction guaranteed), the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound gives $k \le 12$

Comment: I'm not very used to forward error correction, but isn't [reed-solomon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction) supposed to be able to detect t erroneous symbols or correct t/2 erroneous symbols, with t = n - k = 20-16 = 4 => detect 4, correct 2? or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: Even supposing Wikipedia is here right (don't bet on that), $n$ $k$ are not arbitrary - and more important , Reed Solomon is not binary, hence $n=20$ would not mean $n$ bits but $n$ "symbols"

Comment: BTW: 1. You say "without blocks" in the title but then you speak of blocks of 20 bits . Also, "dynamic length" is puzzling in this context. 2 The "amount of block" also is hardly relevant. 3. The remark about RS codes is only relevant for much larger block lenghts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modeling your errors as binomial, let's see what happens if you correct a single error:

The probability of 0 or 1 errors is $$q=(1-p)^{20}+20(1-p)^{19}p$$ which is approximately $0.88$ for $p=0.03,$ so your coded probability of error while correcting one error is $0.12$.

The probability of error with no coding is $1-(1-p)^{20}$ which is around $0.456$ so you do get quite an improvement if you use coding.

According to this paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1933) given $r\geq 3,$ and $2^{r-1}+1\leq n\leq 2^r-1,$ there is an $[n,n-r,3]$ shortened Hamming code with some nice double error detection properties. When $n=20,$ this gives $r=5,$ so you have a $[n,n-r,3]=[20,15,3]$ single error correcting shortened Hamming code and you can transmit $k=15$ bits per block of length $n=20.$